# How to launch Widgets List in android ?

Tags: android

How to launch the widget select menu from my application ?

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
AppWidgetManager manager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo>infoList=manager.getInstalledProviders();
for(AppWidgetProviderInfo info:infoList)
{
   Log.d(TAG, "Name-"+info.name);
  Log.d(TAG, "Configure Name-"+info.configure);
  Log.d(TAG, "Provider Name-"+info.provider);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I wish to launch that activity which is provided from android, using which user selects the widget

Comment: But the "widget activity" you said is only used for <android desktop>, if you want to use it for your app, you must realize all codes and views by yourself.